# ¿Es posible agregar una pipe en css?

Tags: css, angular, json

En mi componente "projects" (uso Angular), al pasar el mouse por un div (hover) de la clase project, sucede una animación en la que se cambia la imagen de fondo lentamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CSS**

```
section{
    background-color: #423549;
}
article{
    padding:5%;
}

h3{
    color: #fa4347;
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    font-size: 4.5rem;
    align-items: center;
}

/***Project***/

#project{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.project{
    background: url({{"src/assets/images/project-color.jpg"}});
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding:1em;
    margin:1em;
    width:50vh;
    height:50vh;
}

.project:hover{
    background: url("src/assets/images/RescateCapuchino.jpg"); /*rellenar dato*/
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: background 2s;
}

#text{
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #fa4347;
}

h4{
    font-size:2.5rem;
}

p{
    font-size:1.5rem;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<section>
    <article>
    <div class="projects-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col text-center">
                <h3>PROYECTOS</h3>
                <app-projects-add-modal></app-projects-add-modal>
            </div>
            <div class="col-9" id="project">
                <div class="project" *ngFor="let project of projects" >
                    <div id="text">
                        <app-projects-edit-modal></app-projects-edit-modal> 
                        <app-delete-modal></app-delete-modal>
                        <h4>{{project.title}}</h4> <!--metodo mayusculas--> 
                        <p>{{project.description}}</p> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </article>
</section>
```

**JSON**

```
...
"projects":
    [
        {
            "id":8,
            "title": "protitle",
            "description": "prodesc",
            "img": "https://cdn.ome.lt/na9I21fxm5PuMF1Pr1bR5fL2ulw=/1200x630/smart/extras/conteudos/Life_is_Strange_-_Max_e_Chloe_57oFbXb.jpg",
            "url": "prourl"
        },
        {
            "id":9,
            "title": "protitle2",
            "description": "prodesc2",
            "img": "https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/93682f1b-8363-4403-997b-b6c5c38e2d73/dbrexfc-14297598-a0d7-42ff-b98c-dd419e40bb3b.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7InBhdGgiOiJcL2ZcLzkzNjgyZjFiLTgzNjMtNDQwMy05OTdiLWI2YzVjMzhlMmQ3M1wvZGJyZXhmYy0xNDI5NzU5OC1hMGQ3LTQyZmYtYjk4Yy1kZDQxOWU0MGJiM2IucG5nIn1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmZpbGUuZG93bmxvYWQiXX0.L64UCdXyacOOI9mKbagvnzotfaILnH4IgsapQQD_ZOA",
            "url": "prourl2"
        }
    ],
...
```

Ahora intento hardcodear todos mis componentes con un json. Y más adelante tengo que dedicarme al back-end.
Como pueden ver, pude hacerlo con el título y la descripción. Mi preocupación es cómo puedo cambiar la imagen del fondo, por eso me pregunto si es posible usar un pipe o ngFor en css... O cuál sería la forma correcta de hacer este código.
Estos fueron algunos mis intentos fallidos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Además, al modificar el html no funciona la animación y no logré que se cargara la imagen especificada en el json. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo para que un pipe, pero el pipe sería útil por si no existe alguna imagen. Para que la imagen cambie cada vez que se le pase por encima solamente necesitas una función:

```
cambiarImagen(imagen, i) {
  this.project[i].img = FUENTE_IMAGEN_NUEVA
};
```

En el HTML:

```
<img [src]="project.img" (mouseover)="cambiarImagen(event,i)">
```

Comment: ... no lo resolvió, quizá no supe aplicarlo, pero me llevó a la respuesta igual jaja copié ese img en mi html y lo saqué del css, y logré el mismo efecto de otra forma. Gracias!!!